# It is posible to get URL to current pipeline execution in Bitbucket Pipelines?

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket-pipelines

Every pipeline execution has their own URL (I think is a kind of UUID?).

It's possible to get that URL or UUID to compose the URL?

I have a command inside my tasks triggering messages using a REST/API call, but I want to include a link to the pipeline that triggered the message.

Answer (score 11):

You can try doing it with [default variables in pipelines](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/variables-in-pipelines-794502608.html). The ones you need are:

- `$BITBUCKET_GIT_HTTP_ORIGIN` - the URL for the origin (e.g. `http://bitbucket.org/<account>/<repo>`).
- `$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER` - the unique identifier for your build.

For the time of writing this answer, the following combination works:

```
$BITBUCKET_GIT_HTTP_ORIGIN/addon/pipelines/home#!/results/$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but a brittle solution. BitBucket should provide this as an environment variable in the build...

Comment: For me the url doesn't contain 'addon' at all, but rather looks like `$BITBUCKET_GIT_HTTP_ORIGIN/pipelines/results/<id>/steps/<some-uuid>`. Totally agree with @MoritzFriedrich.

Answer (score 0):

We can form it using `BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME` and `BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER`, like below,

"https://bitbucket.org/${BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME}/pipelines/results/${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}"